# uploading file is not working in django update forms but working in create

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

i'm using a forms to create and update a form.
template and form is the same but view is different.
the problem is uploading image is working in create but not in update.
no file will not be applied and in post method i receive i get this:

```
/media/<filename>
```

it seems that upload_to path is not applied and no file is uploaded.
here is the model:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='%Y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True)
```

and here is the form:

```
class AddDeviceForm(forms.Form):
  image = forms.ImageField(label='Image', required=False, allow_empty_file=True)

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['image'].widget.attrs.update(
        {'name': 'image', 'class': 'upload'})
```

and here is the template:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% if edit == True %}{% url 'update' device_type serial_number %}{% else %}{% url 'addItem' %}{% endif %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div style="padding-right: 20px; padding-left: 20px">
        {{ form.image.label }}:
        {{ form.image }}
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn">submit</button>
</form>
```

and here is the view:

```
def update(request, device_type, serial_number):
greenhouse = Greenhouse.objects.first()
if greenhouse is None:
    greenhouse = Greenhouse.objects.create()
device = None
if device_type == "1":
    device = LightDevice.objects.filter(serialNumber=serial_number).last()
elif device_type == "2":
    device = TemperatureAndHumidityDevice.objects.filter(serialNumber=serial_number).last()
elif device_type == "3":
    device = SoilTemperatureDevice.objects.filter(serialNumber=serial_number).last()
elif device_type == "4":
    device = SoilHumidityDevice.objects.filter(serialNumber=serial_number).last()
elif device_type == "5":
    device = SoilSalinityDevice.objects.filter(serialNumber=serial_number).last()
elif device_type == "6":
    device = SoilPHDevice.objects.filter(serialNumber=serial_number).last()
if request.method == "POST":
    form = UpdateDeviceForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    print(form.errors)
    if form.is_valid():
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        serial_number = form.cleaned_data['serialNumber']
        image = form.cleaned_data['image']
        if not bool(image):
            image = device.image
        dt = int(form.cleaned_data['type'])
        if dt == 1:
            LightDevice.objects.select_for_update().filter(id=device.id).update(
                name=name, serialNumber=serial_number,
                image=image)
        elif dt == 2:
            TemperatureAndHumidityDevice.objects.select_for_update().filter(id=device.id).update(
                name=name, serialNumber=serial_number,
                image=image)
        elif dt == 3:
            SoilTemperatureDevice.objects.select_for_update().filter(id=device.id).update(
                name=name, serialNumber=serial_number,
                image=image)
        elif dt == 4:
            SoilHumidityDevice.objects.select_for_update().filter(id=device.id).update(
                name=name, serialNumber=serial_number,
                image=image)
        elif dt == 5:
            SoilSalinityDevice.objects.select_for_update().filter(id=device.id).update(
                name=name, serialNumber=serial_number,
                image=image)
        elif dt == 6:
            SoilPHDevice.objects.select_for_update().filter(id=device.id).update(
                name=name, serialNumber=serial_number,
                image=image)
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('data is not valid.')
else:
    if device is not None:
        data = {
            'type': device_type,
            'name': device.name,
            'serialNumber': device.serialNumber,
            'image': device.image,
        }
        form = UpdateDeviceForm(initial=data)
        context = {'form': form, 'greenhouse': greenhouse, 'notifications_count': Alarm.objects.all().count(),
                   'edit': True, 'device_type': device_type, 'serial_number': serial_number}
        return render(request, 'AddItem.html', context)
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Wrong data')
```

above codes are simplified btw.
anyone knows why this happening.

Comment: Share your views? Are you using a ModelForm or just a plain Form?

Comment: @iain-shelvington ModelForm i guess. i just edited.

Comment: Can you please share your update view codes so that  i can help you solve the problem!

Comment: @Abubakari UmarblacKrussain Uma
just edited tnx

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like in your form you are not saving the data, after the conditional statement if form.is_valid. with what you have done after the form is valid the function doesn't know what to do with the data so instead you have to save data when form is valid.To keep things simple i will just pick part of your code that handle the logic on saving valid data.

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = UpdateDeviceForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    print(form.errors)
    if form.is_valid():
       # Valid form data to be save
       form.save() # here is where you save the data
       name = form.cleaned_data['name']
       serial_number = form.cleaned_data['serialNumber']
       image = form.cleaned_data['image']
       if not bool(image):
            image = device.image
        dt = int(form.cleaned_data['type'])
```